# How can I compute n+1 in matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, conditional-statements

Let's say I have matrix `pa` till `pz` as shown below:

```
pa= [0;0;0;0;0]';
pb=[-0.2;-0.2;-0.2;-0.2;0.8]';
pc=[-1.2;0.4;1.9;2.3;9.0]';
pd=[  ];
pe=[  ];
```

till pz

```
Va=pa(1);
Vb=pa(2);
Vc=pa(3);
Vd=pa(4);
Ve=pa(5);
vdt=[1;0.309;-0.809;-0.809;0.309]'
```

Then multiply using this formula

```
Vdtransformation=Vdt*[Va;Vb;Vc;Vd;Ve]
```

I need to multiply

```
Vdtransformation=Vdt*[Va;Vb;Vc;Vd;Ve]
```

But with changing the value of

```
Va=pb(1);Vb=pb(2);Vc=pb(3);Vd=pb(4);Ve=pb(5);
```

And also do it again for

```
Va=pc(1);Vb=pc(2);Vc=pc(3);Vd=pc(4);Ve=pc(5);
```

till pz.

Is there any simpler way to do it? Should i use `bsxfun`?

Comment: try `doc eval` and read the documentation.

Comment: @natan  Some guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let P=[pa,pb,...,pz] be a matrix with 5 lines and the number of letters in the alphabet 
columns.

Do V=Vdt*P. You are done. Each column of V is the Vdtransformation relative to each pa, pb, ...

Comment: the reason i dont do like what u said is because Inner matrix dimensions didnt agree....

Comment: @dan, the dimmensions do agree! Take a careful look! Note that P is a matrix with 5 lines and the number of letters in the alphabet columns and Vdt is 1x5. Thus, V=Vdt(1x5) * P(5xnumberOfLetters); Therefore, the dimmensions do agree!

Comment: ouwh sorry..its my mistakes.thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no logic in writing `Vdt*[Va;Vb;Vc;Vd;Ve]` where you can instead write `Vdt*pa'` which is equivalent, or better see @Daniel answer.

Second, if you want to cycle names of variables you can use `eval`. For example, if my variables are:

```
pa=1;
pb=2;
pc=3;
A=3;
```

and I want to calc `A*pa`, `A*pb`, etc, I can create a string of the letters needed

```
lett=char(97:99); % this creates the string 'abc'
```

Then for loop "

```
for i=1:numel(lett)
    A*eval(['p' lett(i)])
end
```

Comment: as u can see the pa,pb,pc and etc is the matrix..matrix dimensions did'nt agree

Comment: I didn't try to solve your code, just show you the way to use `eval`. If you don't know how to solve the matrix dimension issue, you should read matlab's documentation on matrix manipulations, such as transpose, etc.